# PHP equivalent of MemoryCache

Tags: c#, php

I have been using the C# MemoryCache for a while now with great results. I am not a PHP developer, but this problem has come up and need to fix it fast. I need to be able to use the same sort of key/value par system (like c# MemoryCache)... but in PHP.

I see PHP has shmop_open(), but that has an int as a key. So now you have to store some sort of array with strings referring to id's? Seems very clumsy.

The PHP sample: http://php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php shows the sample with a static array.

How can i have an in-memory key/value pair, that subsequent requests on the php can get the value from the STRING based key.

Comment: Did you check redis or memcached?

Comment: What exactly are the features of MemoryCache that you need besides simply storing data like in a simple global associative array?

Comment: Simply storing data that persists between page requests. Think of it as saving the trip to the DB. With 100 requests a second being exactly the same, there is no need to go off to the DB and come back, just get it out of the cache. (That was just an example... its not a db, but think of it as the same kind of thing)

Comment: I found APC... it uses string key and ttl

Comment: Hence why I said a simple global associative array would probably be enough for the simplest use cases. I should have been more clear. I'm in no way a PHP expert though.